# Non continous eingenvectors over time numerically using Numpy

Tags: numpy, sympy, eigenvector

I'm solving a time dependent eigenvalue problem numerically and symbolic but they are not giving the same solution. The time dependency of the eigenvectors are different.

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from sympy.physics.matrices import msigma
from sympy.physics.quantum import TensorProduct as ts
from sympy.physics.quantum.dagger import Dagger
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

First using the numerical solution I have:

```
#---- writing the matriz----------------
σx = np.matrix([[0,1],[1,0]])
σy = np.matrix([[0,-1j],[1j,0]])
σz = np.matrix([[1,0],[0,-1]])
I = np.eye(2)


Hi = np.kron(np.kron(σx,σx),I) + np.kron(np.kron(σy,σy),I)
Hm = np.kron(I, np.kron(σx,σx)) + np.kron(I,np.kron(σy,σy))
Hf = np.kron(σz, np.kron(I,σz)) + np.kron(I,np.kron(σz,σz))



s = np.linspace(0.00001,.9999,1000)
ω = s.shape[0]
e_dic = {f"e{i}": [] for i in range(8)}
ev_dic = {f"ev{i}": [] for i in range(8)}
for t in s:
    Had = (1-t)*Hi + t*(1-t)*Hm + t*Hf
    vals,vecs = np.linalg.eigh(Had)
    for e,v in zip(e_dic,vals):
        e_dic[e].append(np.real_if_close(v,tol=10))
    for ev, i in zip(ev_dic, range(8)):
        w = np.real_if_close(vecs[:,i],tol=10)
        ev_dic[ev].append(w)
```

As the output of `np.linalg.eigh` are ordered the eigenvalues are continuous in time:

```
for i in e_dic:
    y = e_dic[i]
    plt.plot(s,y,'-',lw=1,label=i)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But the eigenvector aren't continuous (and using `np.linalg.eig`  or `scipy.linalg.eig`  the results are even worsts):

```
for e in ev_dic:
    a = ev_dic[e]
    for i in range(8):
        y = []
        for j in range(len(a)):
            y.append(float(a[j][i]))
        plt.plot(s,np.real(y),'-',lw=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Solving the problem using Sympy I can see that the eigenvectors are continuous

[image]

```
I, x, y, z = sp.eye(2), msigma(1), msigma(2), msigma(3)

t = sp.symbols(r't', real=True, positive=True)
f = sp.Function('f')(t)
g = sp.Function('g')(t)

f = t
g = t

Hi = (ts(x,x,I)+ts(y,y,I))
Hm = (ts(I,x,x)+ts(I,y,y))
Hf = (ts(z,I,z) + ts(I,z,z))

Had = (1-f)*Hi + f*(1-f)*Hm + g*Hf

e_mult_ev = Had.eigenvects()

e = []
ev = []
for i in range(len(e_mult_ev)):
    val, mult, [v_i, v_j] = e_mult_ev[i]
    e.append(val)
    e.append(val)
    ev.append(v_i)
    ev.append(v_j)

evN = [vec/sp.sqrt((Dagger(vec)*vec)[0]) for vec in ev]
```

This is how I've plotted the Sympy eigenvectors:

```
for i in zip(evN):
    for j in range(8):
        a = i[0][j]
        x = a.evalf()
        if x != 0:
            if x == 1:
                x_vals = np.linspace(0.01, .999, 1000, dtype=complex)
                y_vals = [ 1 for x in x_vals]
                plt.plot(np.real(x_vals),np.real(y_vals),lw=2)
            else:
                lam_x = sp.lambdify(t, x, modules=['mpmath'])

                x_vals = np.linspace(0.01, .999, 1000, dtype=complex)

                y_vals = []
                for _x in x_vals:
                    y_vals.append(complex(lam_x(_x)))
                plt.plot(np.real(x_vals),np.real(y_vals),lw=2)
plt.show()
```

For some reason the eigenvectors components are mixing I'm not sure how to proper solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can see from SymPy that every eigenvalue has multiplicity two:

```
In [56]: Had.shape
Out[56]: (8, 8)

In [57]: len(Had.eigenvals())
Out[57]: 4

In [58]: Had.charpoly().as_expr().factor()
Out[58]: 
                                                                                         2
          2 ⎛   3      2          4        3        2                    3       2      ⎞ 
(-λ + 2⋅t) ⋅⎝- λ  - 2⋅λ ⋅t + 4⋅λ⋅t  - 8⋅λ⋅t  + 8⋅λ⋅t  - 8⋅λ⋅t + 4⋅λ + 8⋅t  - 16⋅t  + 8⋅t⎠
```

What this means is that for each eigenvalue there is a 2D space of possible eigenvectors. The `np.linalg.eigh(Had)` function has to somehow choose two particular vectors that span that eigenspace but it is not uniquely determined which vectors those should be. The discontinuities are just in how that choice is made. The eigenspaces are continuous in `t` but the concept of an eigenvector here is not uniquely defined even if normalised.

Comment: But is it possible to rewrite then in a continuous form using numpy?